# Ethereum [Geth PoA]: How to limit queued transactions in terms of waiting time and number?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I am trying to limit queued transactions in terms of waiting time (using `--txpool.lifetime` ) and in terms of number (using `--txpool.globalqueue`) but nothing works,

I am using PoA with geth, I want to limit queued transactions (transactions with high nonce) in txpool.

Anyone can help me to deal with that?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no